# Use inside trait function inside a class in php

Tags: php, symfony4

I am a beginner in PHP.
Here is my trait.
I want to inside these trait function in several ways. So I have created a trait and ass the function. The purpose of reducing code duplications happen.

```
<?php

namespace App\Validation\Common;

use App\Entity\AbstractCustomField;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use SimitiveTranslationsBundle\Provider\TranslationsProvider;

trait ValueValidationTrait{

    public function __construct(
        protected EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        private TranslationsProvider $translationsProvider,
    ) {
    }
    
    public function validateCustomFieldTypesWithValues(string $type, string $value): void
    {
        switch ($type) {
                case AbstractCustomField::TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE) === null) {
                        $this->addViolation($this->translationsProvider->translate(
                            TranslationsProvider::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
                            'entity.user_custom_field_value.message.invalid_boolean_value'
                        ));

                        break;
                    }

                    break;
                case AbstractCustomField::TYPE_NUMERIC_INTEGER:
                    if (
                        filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== 0 &&
                        !(filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
                    ) {
                        $this->addViolation(
                            $this->translationsProvider->translate(
                                TranslationsProvider::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
                                'entity.user_custom_field_value.message.invalid_numeric_value'
                            )
                        );

                        break;
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    $this->addViolation(
                        $this->translationsProvider->translate(
                            TranslationsProvider::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
                            'entity.user_custom_field_value.message.invalid_custom_field_type'
                        )
                    );

                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

and this is my class which I want to call function, I have created function inside trait.

```
?php

namespace App\Validation\User;

use App\Entity\AbstractCustomField;
use App\Entity\CustomField\UserCustomFieldValue;
use App\Entity\CustomField\UserCustomFieldValueOption;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use SimitiveTranslationsBundle\Provider\TranslationsProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use ValueValidationTrait;

/**
 * Validates user custom field values.
 */
class UserCustomFieldValueConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint): void
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof UserCustomFieldValueConstraint) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException(
                $constraint,
                UserCustomFieldValueConstraint::class
            );
        }

        $userCustomFieldValues = $entity->getUserCustomFieldValues();

        if (!empty($userCustomFieldValues)) {
            foreach ($userCustomFieldValues as $userCustomFieldValue) {
                $type = $userCustomFieldValue->getUserCustomField()->getType();
                $value = $userCustomFieldValue->getValue();
                $userCustomFieldValueOption = $userCustomFieldValue->getUserCustomFieldValueOption();

                if (
                    in_array(
                        $type,
                        AbstractCustomField::getCustomFieldTypesWithValues()
                    ) &&
                    !empty($value)
                ) {
                    $this->validateCustomFieldTypesWithValues($type, $value);
                }

                if (
                    in_array($type, AbstractCustomField::getCustomFieldsTypesWithOptions()) &&
                    !empty($userCustomFieldValueOption)
                ) {
                    $this->validateUserCustomFieldTypesWithOptions(
                        $userCustomFieldValueOption,
                        $userCustomFieldValue
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I call`$this->validateCustomFieldTypesWithValues($type, $value);` as inside trait `validateCustomFieldTypesWithValues(string $type, string $value)` function. It gives an error. Can you suggest to me the way to call the trait function

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by existing code bases. trait should be use inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include trait in the class.

```
class UserCustomFieldValueConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
  use ValueValidationTrait;

  //other functions
}
```

Comment: Is that not what the OP said about 45 minutes before you?  But you got it right.  That's what matters.